# Linq query to join two tables and return object from first table - PagedList used

Tags: entity-framework, linq, lambda, pagedlist

I use Entity framework (code firs model)
I have table `Posts(postID | Title | ...)` and table `Comments(commentID | Comment | postID | userID | CommentDate | ...)`

I want a list of Posts based on a criteria of userID in comments.

```
var listOfPosts = (from p in db.Posts
                    join coment in db.Comments
                    on p.postID equals coment.postID                                
                    where coment.userID == "Some value"
                    orderby coment.CommentDate descending
                    select p).ToList();


return View("ReportList", listOfReports.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

Also I use PagedList for pagination of posts.

But I want the result to be group by PostID so i modified the code as follows

```
var listOfPosts = (from p in db.Posts
                    join coment in db.Comments
                    on p.postID equals coment.postID
                    where coment.userID == "Some value"
                    orderby coment.CommentDate descending
                    group p by p.postID into newP
                    select newP).ToList();
```

The problem here is that the result of second query returns `List<IGrouping<int, Posts>>` and `ToPagedList` method of PagedList works only with `List<Posts>`

How to change the query to return distinct list of posts based on criteria and order of comments?
You could use lambda expression or query syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use subquery and distinct on the outer query like below:

```
var listOfPosts = (from b in ((from p in db.Posts
                               join coment in db.Comments on p.postID equals coment.postID
                               where coment.userID == "Some value"
                               orderby coment.ComentDate descending
                               select p).ToList())
                   select b).Distinct().ToList();
```